# MySQL return single row of multiple invoice due for notification

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Trying to create a notification mail to my clients that have invoices due.

Here is my table

```
Name     Amount  Duedate
Joe@blah 10.00 2011-04-13
Joe@blah 15.00 2011-04-13
Jill@ugg 20.00 2011-05-20
Jim@yuck 25.00 2011-04-13
Joe@blah 15.00 2011-05-20
```

Because Joe is in there twice, how do I supress the second joe, so I don't notify him twice.  I'd like it to return only:

```
Joe@blah
Jim@yuck
```

How do i do this in mysql?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Name FROM Table WHERE DueDate (<=> meets your criteria of when it's "due")
```

Since you're only selecting on Name the DISTINCTROW will only return one instance of each Name.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM your_table WHERE Duedate < NOW()
```

[SELECT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) look at `DISTINCT` section

Answer (score 0):

This query should give you unique names with due date falls in past or today.

```
Select 
B.*
From
Invoicetable A,
(SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Invoicetable WHERE Duedate <= NOW) B
where
A.Name = B.Name
```